# Postgres on trigger an event syntax error at or near "AT"

Tags: mysql, postgresql

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "AT"

This query works with Mysql perfectly but does not work in Postgres.
*So* How to make it work in Postgres?

```sql
CREATE EVENT expireToken
        ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL  1 DAY 
        DO
        DELETE FROM verification_tokens WHERE createdAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: You might want to check the second answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43937/how-to-run-recurring-tasks-on-postgresql-without-an-external-cron-like-tool

Answer (score 1):

That is not a standard SQL statement, so you shouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work in all databases.

If you want to schedule jobs, use `cron` or a PostgreSQL extension like `pg_cron`.